# Why the bitmap created by CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface not match with my draw operation?

Tags: c++11, windows-8, directx, directx-11, wic

As we know, we can use WriteFrame to save bitmap to file in wic.

Here in the method [WriteFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh880845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),we can see a parameter ID2D1Bitmap object.When I use

```
m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(surface.Get(),&bitmapProperties,&myBitmap);
```

and then pass myBitmap to WriteFrame,I can't get the bitmap,it show me a black image.
But when I use

```
m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(pB.Get(), &m_Bitmap);
```

and pass m_Bitmap to WriteFrame, I can get the correct bitmap in the image file.
Why this happen?

Can anyone help. Thank you.

Comment: This might have to do with the fact that a bitmap created from a DXGI surface is an abstraction over a hardware surface. This is something that you *write to*; it's usually a bad idea to view this as a bitmap in the "query bits from here" sense (indeed, one has to jump through hoops to get bits from a IDXGISurface bitmap). What HRESULT does WriteFrame return?

Comment: @susmits WriteFrame returns S_OK.I also think that the surface bitmap is just used to drawing to, rather than drawing from.However,there is no documents say about this.It's a pity.